# Equivalence of two statment for Maschke's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

> **Theorem:** Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$ and let $K$ be a field so that $\text{Char}(K)$ is either $0$ or prime to $n$. Suppose that $A(x)$ is a matrix representation of $G$ such that $A(x)\sim \pmatrix{C(x)_{r\times r}&0\\E(x)&D(x)_{s\times s}}$. Then $A(x)$ can be diagonalized.
> **Solution:** We need to find a non singular $T$ over $K$ independent of $x\in G$ such that, $T^{-1}A(x)T=\pmatrix{C(x)&0\\0&D(x)}$. Assuming $T=\pmatrix{I_r&0\\Q&I_s}$ then we find, $$E(x)+D(x)Q=QC(x)\quad\forall x\in G\tag1$$Now we need to show that such $Q$ exist.
> $$
> \begin{align}
> E(xy)&=E(x)E(y)+D(x)E(y)\\
> E(xy)C(y^{-1})&=E(x)+D(x)E(y)C(y^{-1})\\
> \sum_{y}E(xy)C(y^{-1})&=\sum_{y}E(x)+\sum_{y}D(x)E(y)C(y^{-1})\\
> \sum_{z}E(z)C(z^{-1}x)&=n\:E(x)+D(x)\sum_{y}E(y)C(y^{-1})\quad \text{letting }z=xy\\
> \sum_{y}E(y)C(y^{-1}x)&=n\:E(x)+D(x)\sum_{y}E(y)C(y^{-1})\\
> \left( \sum_{y}E(y)C(y^{-1}) \right) C(y^{-1})&=n\:E(x)+D(x) \left( \sum_{y}E(y)C(y^{-1}) \right)\\
> QC(y^{-1})&=n\:E(x)+D(x) Q\quad \text{letting }Q=\frac1n\left( \sum_{y}E(y)C(y^{-1}) \right)
> \end{align}
> $$

There was another version of Maschke's theorem on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem#Group-theoretic),

> $V$ is a representation of a finite group $G$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ with characteristic not dividing the order of $G$. If $V$ has a subrepresentation $W$, then it has another subrepresentation $U$ such that $V=W\oplus U$.

How are these two versions related with?

The assumption, $\text{Char}(K)$ is either $0$ or prime to $n$ is needed because we need to ensure $|G|$ is invertible. But I didn't manage to understand the counterexample mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3826821/1167703). I start learning group representation recently. It will be a great help if anyone suggest me a good resource on matrix representation in a great detail. TIA

Answer (score 0):

The last columns of $A(x)$ provide an $s$-dimensional matrix representation by acting on the $s$-dimensional subspace of vectors whose only nonzero coordinates are among the last $s$ ones. This $D(x)$ is a subrepresentation of $A(x)$. The theorem is concerned with finding a subrepresentation $F(x)$ that $A(x) \cong D(x) \oplus F(x) = D(x) \oplus T \mathrm{diag}(0_{r\times r},C(x)) T^{-1}$ (note that $C(x)$ isn't really a subrepresentation of $A(x)$).

In a similar way, the $C_p$ representation $k \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1&k\\&1\end{pmatrix}$ over $\Bbb F_p$ has a subrepresentation $S$ that acts on the span of the first basis vector. As it is written e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110852/counterexample-for-maschkes-lemma-for-two-dimensional-representations-of-math?noredirect=1&lq=1), the matrices of $S$ (except the identity) cannot be brought to diagonal forms by similarity transformations (alternatively to the multiplicities argument, you can pass to the algebraic closure of $\Bbb F_p$ and use the Jordan normal form theory: not even in a larger field these matrices are similar to diagonal ones). Over a **characteristic $0$ field** with a **finite** group you won't be able to come up with such examples. For completeness, a very *similar* counterexample for the infinite case you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121365/show-that-the-representation-mathbb-z-ni-a-mapsto-beginpmatrix1-a-01-end).

As for the references, there are a [lot](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336238/reference-request-representation-theory) of [books](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192721/best-books-on-representation-theory) that were [recommended](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363297/good-book-on-representation-theory-after-reading-rotman) on MSE. I'll go with J. P. Serre *Linear representations of finite groups* and C. W. Curtis, I. Reiner *Representation theory of finite groups and associative algebras* (this specific title — there are also advanced books by these authors).